# QDesktopWidget doesn't emit any signal at screen resolution change or monitors count

Tags: c++, macos, qt, qt4, osx-mavericks

I'm testing on Mac OS 10.9.1 with Qt 4.8.5
The same code works on Windows and I'm pretty sure it worked before update from the MacOS 10.8.

```
private slots:

void desktopResized(int screen);
void desktopScreenCountChanged(int newCount);

...

bool result = connect(qApp->desktop(), SIGNAL(resized(int)), SLOT(desktopResized(int)));
Q_ASSERT(result);
connect(qApp->desktop(), SIGNAL(screenCountChanged(int)), SLOT(desktopScreenCountChanged(int)));
```

Slots just never get called on change of monitor resolution.
Does anyone have the same problem, any solution? Thanks

[UPDATE] The bug is resolved in Qt 5.2.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a [bug report](https://bugreports.qt-project.org/browse/QTBUG-34515?page=com.atlassian.streams.streams-jira-plugin%3aactivity-stream-issue-tab) about this. 
Hasn't been evaluated yet though